# I'd like to see the last few IP addresses that my account was used from, please!

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, revisions-list, security

I think that as a matter of security (in the [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) age) I'd like to see the last IP address from which my account was accessed next to my name, somewhere in the top bar. I'd also ideally like a history of my IP addresses (available only to me) in my account summary.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:**

Right now, it shows the "last activity from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx N hours ago." or "Last activity from this IP address N hours ago."

I want two changes. Firstly, I want to see the last IP address *even if* it's the same one, as in: "Last activity from this IP address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) N hours ago.)

Also, I want a new tab with all of my recent IP addresses, similar to Gmail.

Comment: It no longer shows "last activity from X".

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a really good idea, and I'd like to see a history of IPs too.

**Edit:** I think this could work well even as a tab in the user column, instead of a separate window.

Putting it next to where the user feed could work well.

> [image: Demo]

Obviously this could be designed better, but it could be in gray and show a popup like:

[image: IP Dialog]

Answer (score -3):

You can already see it in your profile page:

> [image]

Comment: OP knows about that -- not downvoting or anything, he said it in chat -- but per this question, he wants it displayed more prominently, and wants a history. (A previous answerer already posted this answer, but deleted it after I posted a comment much like this one.)

Comment: @Pop You should probably post that comment to the question, or just edit it into the question.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I'll leave it for the next answerer then `:P`. There's really no way of knowing that from the question...

Comment: Yes, I know about that. @Kobi - What is unclear from the question, I'll gladly clarify.

Comment: Looks like this went away when profile pages were redesigned?

Comment: Yup, this doesn't exist for long years by now.