# Can I track the IP address used to post on SE using my non-account email?

Tags: support, user-accounts, new-users

Someone posted something on SE using an email address I own (it's publicly posted on my SE profile so there was no rocket surgery level hacking involved :)

<sub>Just to be clear - this is the public-facing email address created about a week ago, **different** from actual email address I use to sign up for my SE login.</sub>

As designed, SE sent me an email, "Thanks for your post on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange", which includes the "Set Your Password" link.

Is there a way to track the IP address of who sent it from the "Set Your Password" link or any other information, short of contacting SE team to go through their internal logs?

If possible I'd like to avoid [this solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71447/119280) which requires me to actually log in to the new fake account and use it.

Comment: The "solution" on the other question doesn't work anymore, as that line is no longer on the profile page. Even if it was, if it's been more than 15 minutes since they were seen, the most recent IP address would be changed to yours along with the last activity date the moment you signed into the account. So I'm not sure why that was ever considered useful.

Comment: @animuson - thanks. The latter part of your answer is exactly why I considered that solution to be undesirable - as I never logged into the account, I didn't want to trample IP fingerprints.

Comment: [Feature request based on this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273315/lets-show-users-an-audit-of-account-activity)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, this is something we want people to contact us about, because we'd like to be able to make sure the extent of the shenanigans *are in fact* confined to just that address. We'd also like to see what those IPs have been up to :)

I'm not *overly* against showing users the IP address that requested account-facing things - in fact I kind of like how Gmail shows me that I'm logged in from multiple places (just as an example). But that's really getting into a bigger feature.

Can you start with [contacting us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), and we'll go from there? 
I can't promise anything, though, without the details, and we kinda need to take this offline in order to talk about them.

Comment: Damn, why couldn't this happen during Winter Bash? I could have posted "lack of IP tracking in email" as a bug and gotten a pretty hat! Email sent, thanks.

Comment: Message sent. Thank you.